# The alert is displayed with a transparent background instead of a solid color

Tags: html, css

If the alert has fewer points, it has a solid color, as it grows it becomes transparent, how can I solve it?
code CSS

```
   .div-error{
          
    justify-content: center;
  
   position: fixed;
   left: 40%;
   top: 20%;
    
}
.text-error{
    color: red !important;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

[image: various alert points]

Comment: Show your html and css code

Comment: I already added my CSS code

Comment: what is actually your problem? that it becomes more transparent and you want the color to be static/fixed or how you get the color to change from a fixed color to be mroe transparent? transperency is dont through RGBA. And for that you also need JS. However with more detail and codes this task is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

I share here a responsive development of an alert box, this is my own code, you can copy the css of this for your own alert. This

```js
function openAlert(status, message) {
  $("#AlertGeneralContent").html(message);
  $("#AlertGeneral").removeClass();
  $("#AlertGeneral").addClass(status+" show");
}

function closeAlert() {
  $("#AlertGeneral").removeClass("show");  
}
```

```css
#AlertGeneral {
  position: fixed;
  height: fit-content;
  width: 450px;
  max-width: 90%;
  bottom: 30px;
  right: 10px;
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  display: none;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  z-index: 10000;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 50px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) !important;
}
#AlertGeneral.show{ display: block !important; }
#AlertGeneral.Success{ background-color: #4CAF50; }
#AlertGeneral.Info{ background-color: #2196F3; }
#AlertGeneral.Warning{ background-color: #ff9800; }
#AlertGeneral.Danger{ background-color: #f44336; }
#AlertGeneralClose {
  margin-top: -10px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 35px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
#AlertGeneralClose:hover { color: black; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <body>
    <button style="background-color: green;" onclick="openAlert('Success','Great!')">Success</button>
    <button style="background-color: yellow;" onclick="openAlert('Warning','Not like this!')">Warning</button>
    <button style="background-color: red; color: white;" onclick="openAlert('Danger','Careful!')">Danger</button>
    <button style="background-color: blue; color: white;" onclick="openAlert('Info','Lorem Ipsum has been the industry\'s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesettingLorem Ipsum has been the industry\'s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesettingLorem Ipsum has been the industry\'s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesettingLorem Ipsum has been the industry\'s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesettingLorem Ipsum has been the industry\'s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesettingLorem Ipsum has been the industry\'s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting')">Long Text</button>
    <div id="AlertGeneral">
      <span id="AlertGeneralClose" onclick="closeAlert()">&times;</span>
      <div id="AlertGeneralContent"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the background-color property for a solid filled color.

Ex.

```
.text-error{
background-color: red !important;
font-weight: bold;
```

}